# Converting DataTable to anonymous two-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm struggling a little bit with this and can't seem to find an answer here. I am using the SautinSoft Document plug-in to create a mail merge in MS Word. The data source is my issue. My data in a DataTable, whereas the function they have coded to pass the data is in an anonymous array:

```
        var dataSource = new[] 
        { new { FirstName = "Hector", LastName = "Stupid", Age = "40" },  
          new { FirstName = "Penelope ", LastName = "Plank", Age = "25" }
        };
```

So, I need to iterate through my DataTable populating the fields into this format with their values.

Then, I execute the Mail Merge thus:

```
        dc.MailMerge.Execute(dataSource);
```

The question is how? Since the array is being statically populated. I've tried many solutions, passing either the DataTable, converting to a Dictionary, and .ToArray() over Ienumerable, but nothing seems to replicate this format.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is `datasource.Select(row => new { FirstName = row.whatever, LastName = row.whateverelse, Age = row.whatever }).ToArray()` not working for you?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `AsEnumerable` method let `DataTable` to `IEnumerable<Row>` then use `select` fill data.

```
datasource
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new {
        FirstName = row["FirstName"],
        LastName = row["LastName"],
        Age = row["Age"]
    }).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Comment: @DavyC No problem glad to help you can mark this answer if that help you :)